# html in mail doesn't shows up. Inline images does

Tags: php, html, css, email

I wrote following piece of code:

[SOLVED]

I've tried everything and this piece of code seems fine for me.

Regards,
Andy

Comment: the html support in email clients  is limited, not everything a browser supports is supported in every email client

Comment: Some email clients handle backgrounds/images differently than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many email clients ignore background colors specified in the `<body>` tag.

Use a container table instead:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#000000">
            hello world!
            <img src="cid:bg.png">
            footer
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Yes, it's a lot of extra HTML code. Building HTML emails that perform well in the majority of email clients can be painful.

Some helpful references:

1. http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/
2. http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

`rgb(0, 0, 0)` is not supported in older email clients use instead regular background colors.

Also, for email clients is better to use tables instead of div tags.

Comment: Looking at http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/hexadecimal_vs_rgb_values_in_html_emails it appears that `rgb` background colors are supported in everything except older versions of Lotus Notes.